# hat path to go for simple Android app development Unity or Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get into android app development.

Finding it hard to choose which way to go, I've read numerous threads about unity/android studio. But none which really answer my question. What path should I go on if I want to create apps like trivia, knowledge, number, puzzle (e.g. Fill one-line game) apps like this? Is Unity really needed to make these types of apps? or is android studio sufficient?

I would prefer the coding route but how much more effort would it be than using Unity to create apps like this?

Comment: AFAIK, you only build scenes in Unity, not create the code that links the Unity project to other platforms (Android, iOS, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO It really depends on the complexity of what you are trying to do. Both can work of course.

To keep it simple, I would say if you are planning to add to you game a lot of features, use 3D, add lightning, cool animations, complex interactions or stuff like that, it would be better to use a game engine to do it, so Unity here, then build it for Android (Unity does that easily).

If this is something simple, with not too many things, developing it using Android Studio might be simpler.

If you're unsure, the best thing would be to list all the functionalities you want for your game/app and search how to do them on both platforms, you might find out that one will be easier to use than another for one important feature.